# Django Matching query does not exist for male

Tags: python, django

Basically I can update for the contact part where male,female and contact are in same form in 3 different columns. I have three models for them and the problem arises when I try to update the male or female column inputs where I can update the contact. Help please.
When I try, I get DoesNotExist at /update/40/

Male matching query does not exist.

[image: my img]

views.py

```
def update(request,pk_test):
    male = Male.objects.get(id=pk_test) 
    m_form = maleForm(instance=male)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        m_form = maleForm(request.POST,instance=male)
    
        if m_form.is_valid() :
            m_form.save()
            return redirect('info')
    context = {

        'm_form' : m_form
    }
    template_name = 'add.html' 
    return render(request , template_name , context)
```

forms.py

```
class maleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Male  
        fields = ('chest' , 'neck' , 'full_shoulder_width' ,'right_sleeve' , 'left_sleeve' ,'bicep' )
```

urls.py

```
path('update/<int:pk_test>/', views.update, name='update'),
```

models.py

```
class Male(models.Model):
    
    contact1 = models.ForeignKey(Contact,  on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    chest = models.CharField(max_length=30 , blank=True)
    neck = models.CharField(max_length=30 , blank=True)
    full_shoulder_width = models.CharField(max_length=30 , blank=True)
    right_sleeve = models.CharField(max_length=30 , blank=True)
    left_sleeve = models.CharField(max_length=30 , blank=True)
    bicep = models.CharField(max_length=30 , blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
       return str(self.contact1)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this means that the object you are trying to get does not exist. Are you sure there's a `Male` object with the id of 40?

Comment: I tried checking new contact + male inputs.now the query for all giving same error.

Comment: Why are you check this c_form.is_valid()? I dont found c_form. You can check also`` male = get_object_or_404(Male, pk=pk_test)

Comment: ops that was a small typo but still not fixing

Comment: may I know from where are you  getting pk_test from? Need more code

Comment: check from here https://pastebin.com/vNsBxz1N

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not id it is **pk(primary key)**. 
try using primary key

```
def update(request,pk_test):
    male = Male.objects.get(pk=pk_test) 
    m_form = maleForm(instance=male)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        m_form = maleForm(request.POST,instance=male)
    
        if m_form.is_valid() and c_form.is_valid():
            m_form.save()
            return redirect('info')
    context = {

        'm_form' : m_form
    }
    template_name = 'add.html' 
    return render(request , template_name , context)
```

Comment: not working.
if i give male = Contact.objects.get(pk=pk_test)  this only save the contact column inputs but not for the male or female

Answer (score 0):

1. Wrap the `Male.objects.get(pk=pk_test)` into a `try except` block since `Model.objects.get` throws exception if object is not available.
2. change `id=pk_test` to `pk=pk_test`

```py
def update(request,pk_test):
    m_form = None
    try:
        male = Male.objects.get(pk=pk_test)
        m_form = maleForm(instance=male)
    except:
        male = None
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        m_form = maleForm(request.POST,instance=male)
    
        if m_form.is_valid() :
            m_form.save()
            return redirect('info')
    context = {

        'm_form' : m_form
    }
    template_name = 'add.html' 
    return render(request , template_name , context)
```

Comment: It creates new one rather than updating the existing.
can u check this and find out the problem ?https://pastebin.com/vNsBxz1N

Comment: Please put a print inside try and except and check if the data is already there or not.

Comment: I can update for the male and contact but not for the female.Whenever i create new contact with female,it gets added but when I try to update it I get none value for it

Comment: You have to make changes similar to Male. For django these are just models and for django these are same.

Comment: can u check this if it is right or not?
veiws.py  https://pastebin.com/ybi3U63y
models.py  https://pastebin.com/9u1GS6AA
forms.py  https://pastebin.com/xdgAtAsK
urls.py https://pastebin.com/2icFqSK2

Comment: Why are you using `id=pk_test`? You did the same mistake with Male also. Please refer Male model update functionality and try to fix this. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get

Comment: though i used pk=pk_test result was same